# Binding not update in Command

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've a listbox that contains some "Application" object.
An "Application" object can be started or stopped.

For each element in my Listbox I've 2 buttons, the first to start application and the second to stop the application.

But, when I click on Start button, it doesn't update the binding "IsRunning" Correctly.
The CanExecute of command is reevaluated when I click inside of application, despite the "CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();"

So, my start button remains enabled and my stop button is never displayed.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFE8E8E8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Margin="5,0" Content = "Start" 
              Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
              Visibility="{Binding IsRunning, Converter={Converters:InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
      <Button Margin="5,0"  Content = "Stop" 
              Command="{Binding StopCommand}"
              Visibility="{Binding IsRunning, Converter={Converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

On ApplicationViewModel :

```
public bool IsRunning
{
  get
  {
    return this.m_IsRunning;
  }
  set
  {
    this.m_IsRunning = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsRunning");
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
  }
}
```

Comment: Stupid question: Do you update `IsRunning` in the command callback? Do you update `m_IsRunning`?

Comment: Yes, IsRunning has been updated because in another view every things are correctly updated ...

Comment: OMG! Sorry, It's correct... In another thread I set m_IsRunning and not IsRunning...

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen converters referenced like these. You need to create them somwhere and then reference them using `StaticResource`/`DynamicResource`:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Converters:InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="invBoolConv"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Margin="5,0" Content = "Start" 
        Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsRunning, Converter={StaticResource invBoolConv}"/>
```